# How can I define the intersection area of an ellipse and a circle if there is 4 intersection points?

Tags: integration, geometry, circles, area

So I would need to solve how to define the intersection area of a circle and an ellipse if they had 4 intersection points. Radius of circle is 2000 and it's x- and y- coordinates are (5000,5000). Ellipse's x- and y-coordinates are also (5000,5000), semi-major axis = 3500 and minor-axis = 1500. [image: Here is image of the setup].

I would appreciate a ton if someone could help me with practical solution step by step.
I know that first we have to figure out the intersection points and after that integrate the area but I don't know how to do it in practice.

Comment: In an example like this I'd draw the rectangle with vertices the four points of intersection; the area of overlap consists of this rectangle plus two segments of the circle plus two segments of the ellipse.

Comment: As the coordinates of their center are same, you can assume them to be (0,0,0) for simplicity while calculating area of intersection, as you know the radius of the circle and the semi-major and semi-minor axes of the ellipse.

Comment: Do you know how to use integration? Do you know how to get the equations for a circle and ellipse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Put the center of ellipse and circle at the origin. The equation of ellipse is:

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1\tag{1}$$

...and the equation of the circle is $$x^2+y^2=r^2\tag{2}$$

...with $a=3500,b=1500,r=2000$

Solve equautions (1) and (2) for positive values of $x,y$ and you'll get coordinates of point $A$:

$$x_A=175\sqrt{70},\ \  y_A=75 \sqrt{330}$$

Now you have to calculate the area $CAB$ between curves $BA$ and $CA$ and vertical  segment $BC$. The equation of curve $AB$ is:

$$y=\frac ba\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$$

...and the equation of curve $AC$ is:

$$y=\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$$

So the area of $P_{ABC}$ is:

$$P_{ABC}=\int_0^{x_A}(\sqrt{r^2-x^2}-\frac ba\sqrt{a^2-x^2})dx$$

$$P_{ABC}=125000 \left(16 \sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{7 \sqrt{\frac{7}{10}}}{8}\right)-21 \sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{\frac{7}{10}}}{2}\right)\right)\approx509768$$

The are of intersection is:

$$P=r^2\pi-4P_{ABC}\approx 1.05273\times10^7$$

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. You saved my day, thank you!